# more extensive example implementation code for react-pouchdb-changes

Tags: reactjs, pouchdb

I'm brand new to both pouchdb and react. I found the [react-pouchdb-changes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pouchdb-changes) module which seems exactly like what I want to be using.

However, the example code it provides is far too sparse - I'm really at a loss as to how it would be incorporated into a basic react application.

Can someone provide a more complete example usage with some basic explanations of what each piece does?

Answer (score 0):

This module seems to be merely a wrapper for the `changes` method. You can get a live example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/7c32861af5d31a8fac4a). The link comes right from the [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html).

If that's not enough info you can check out the [API reference](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) with examples and example responses.

Comment: Thanks. I have a handle on how the pouchdb part works, but I'm not clear on how it integrates with react. The example provided seems to show pseudo code, and it doesn't explain how I would incorporate into my react app. For example, my app starts with: " var Basebuilder = React.createClass({" - would I instead extend PouchDBChanges?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you want react-pouchdb-changes to integrate with React. All it does is provide you with a component to put your onChange handler on. These parts of the code example are the relevant ones:

```
<PouchDBChanges
  …
  onChange={change => console.log(change) /* do something useful with the change here instead of just logging it! */}
>
 {/* your <App> component here */}
</PouchDBChanges>
```

Just use the component in your JSX code (wrap your main component or any container component with it).

If you have difficulties with setting up a React example, try using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). You'll have a running React app within a few seconds. A good place to add your `<PouchDBChanges>` component would be [src/App.js](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/App.js) - just wrap the outermost `<div>` with the component.